# R httr package - Make POST request to an API with body

Tags: r, postman, httr

I try to make a post request to my API. In Postman it looks like this:

POST:
`http://localhost:5000/api/login`
body:
`{"secret": "bla"}`

This gives me back an access token which works fine. I try the same with the `httr` packge like this:

```
login <- list(
  secret = "bla"
)

httr::POST("http://localhost:5000/api/login", body = login, verbose(), content_type("application/json"))
```

This is the verbose output, I don´t know why I get back a 400 error.

```
-> POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: localhost:5000
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.1
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 145
-> Content-Type: application/json; boundary=------------------------a4dc23f1d3e7221e
-> 
>> --------------------------a4dc23f1d3e7221e
>> Content-Disposition: attachment; name="secret"
>> 
>> bla
>> --------------------------a4dc23f1d3e7221e--

<- HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
<- Content-Type: application/json
<- Content-Length: 91
<- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<- Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.7.6
<- Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 15:14:54 GMT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make sure the body is a json character vector instead of an r list.

```
httr::POST("http://localhost:5000/api/login", body = jsonlite::toJSON(login), verbose(), content_type("application/json"))
```

Comment: great, thank you! Throught httr does this under the hood :-)

Comment: No problem. It does some stuff, but not others. Hard to keep track.

Comment: in fact, I think it is enough to add `encode = "json"` argument, and then you won't need to manually convert the body

Comment: Might be true. I haven't tried. But that would be a nice convenience.

Comment: this answer saved my day. In my app one input feature into the model is a variable length vector, based on user input that could be multiple selection. Without the jsonlite::toJSON() decoration, when user select a single option, the nested list would be converted by the httr::POST() to {'data':{'feat_1':'a'}}, which is not recognized by the API, with the decoration, the payload will be {'data':{'feat_1':['a']).